# Spring Tiles not be used for login pages, but for all other pages after login

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I am trying to develop and web application using Spring MVC, where i am planning to use tiles. Now the problem is I do not want to use Tiles for login page which would be my first page. But all the subsequent pages should use Tiles thereafter which includes HEADER(constatnt), MENU(dynamic based on the type of used logged in), BODY(Dynamic based on the menu selected), FOOTER(Constant).

Please suggest, as i am new for both spring and tiles.

BR

Comment: please give us more information what you are using. (jquery, jsp, ...)

Comment: i just want my first page to be plane jsp page and then after sucesful login i want the home page with tiles and menus based on the logged in user.

Comment: i dont get it: if you dont want to use tiles on your login page, then dont include them